# Why is the Laplacian operator hermitian?

Tags: differential-geometry, laplacian

There should be some general proof. Of course, proper boundary condition is needed. Here, the manifold is a general Riemann manifold.

Can anyone give one?

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35210/the-hermiticity-of-the-laplacian-and-other-operators

Answer (score 6):

You just need the integration by parts formula $$ \int \nabla f \cdot X=-\int f \operatorname{div} X,$$
which holds for any vector field $X$ and function $f$ such that $fX=0$ on the boundary of your manifold. (You can derive this by applying the divergence theorem to the vector field $f X$.)

Thus for any $f,g$ vanishing on the boundary we have
$$\langle f, \Delta g \rangle = \int f\ \overline{\operatorname{div}(\nabla g)} = -\int \nabla f \cdot \overline{\nabla g} = \int \operatorname{div}(\nabla f) \ \bar g=\langle \Delta f, g\rangle.$$